# On the averages of bounded continuous functions

Tags: analysis

For a continuous $f\colon\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow[0,1]$, what could be said about $\mathcal{F}=\{f_r\colon r>0\}$ where $$\forall\,r>0,\,\forall\,z\!\in\!\mathbb{C},\quad f_r(z)=\frac{1}{|\mathcal{B}_r|}\int_{\mathcal{B}_r}f(z+u)\mathrm{d}u$$
$B_r$ denotes the ball $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon\,|z|\leq r\}$, and $|B_r|$ denotes its area.

For a given $r>0$, is $f_r$ *uniformly continuous* or *Lipschitzien*?
Are members of $\mathcal{F}$ *uniformly equicontinous*?
Is $\mathcal{F}$ *compact* with respect to the *sup norm*?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? What theorems have you covered lately?

Comment: @Umberto Not a homework problem, but proving compactness (if possible) is very convenient to prove other properties for $f$ with additional assumptions ...