# On the compactness of a set of functions that satisfy mean value property

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Consider $\mathcal{C}$ the subset of functions $\varphi\colon\mathbb{C}\rightarrow[0,1]$ that satisfy the following properties:
$(1)\,\exists\,\varepsilon\colon\mathbb{R}\!\rightarrow\!(0,\infty)$ *s.t.* $\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\varepsilon}(x)\!\rightarrow\!0$ **and** $\forall\varphi\!\in\!\mathcal{C},\,\forall z_1,z_2\!\in\!\mathbb{C},\,|\varphi(z_1)\!-\!\varphi(z_2)|\leq\varepsilon(|z_1\!-\!z_2|)$.
$(2)$ The average of $\varphi$ on every unit-radius circle centered at $z$ is $\varphi(z)$.
Is it true that $\mathcal{C}$ is compact with respect to the uniform norm?

Comment: Does $\epsilon$in (1) depends on $\phi$?

Comment: Is it one $\epsilon$ for all $\phi$ or is it for each $\phi,$ there is an $\epsilon_\phi?$

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification @N.S. and @zhw! $\varepsilon$ is fixed for all members of $\mathcal{C}$ (*i.e.* independent of $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}$).

Comment: I found [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202763/on-the-averages-of-bounded-continuous-functions?rq=1), but it's unfortunately unanswered.